# Check If first character is "+"

Tags: regex, tasker

How can i detect string is start with `"+"`

I tried
`^\s*?\+.*$`
but no help.

P.s: I have only one line alltime.

Comment: That should work fine, although the `?` is unnecessary. In fact, the `.*$` at the end is also unnecessary. You can test this yourself at https://regex101.com/

Comment: Hmm Tasker Conditions not recognize them. Interesting.

Comment: It is said it is [not possible](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/ru/matching.html). Wow. Looks like some wildcard, not a regex.

Comment: `^\s*\+` working if I select "Matches Regex" as Condition Operator in Tasker.

Comment: So, no lazy matching is available in tasker. :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need `\s*?`, you have to use:

```
^\+
or...
^[+]
```

In case you want to check a complete string, you can use:

```
^\+.*$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJ6vA0/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, you can also use native method [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

So it would be:

```
var str1 = '+some text';
var bool = str1.startsWith('+'); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

`^\+.*$` should work for your purposes.

Here's a fiddle with a couple test strings : https://regex101.com/r/nP2eL7/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's an optional (and optimal) solution in the case that the first character of your string happens to be either a `+` or `-` and you don't want the proceeding number to have any leading zeros:

```
/(?<=^\+|-|^)[1-9]\d*/
```